# Which one would be faster: redis scan with match or retrieving possible keys from mysql first?

Tags: python, mysql, redis

Let's assume we're having a redis instance with multimillion keys. These keys consist of two parts: idX:idY.

To retrieve all values for the keys that contain idx=1234 (which are about five at maximum)  would it be faster to scan all keys with a match for idx=1234 or would it be faster to retrieve all possible idY keys first from a MySQL database (which are about 20) and try to retrieve the values from redis for those 20 idX:idY keys?

Comment: Have you considered putting the list of idY values for a given idX into another Redis key?

Comment: Actually, I have thought about that. But as I wanted to use TTL for entries I would need a way to delete the idY out of that key list when the entry is deleted. I haven't thought much about it, but my quick research led me to believe that this is not that easy.

Comment: But at least the list of 20 possibilities would be quick to fetch, then you could check each of them. If some of those 20 have expired from their TTL, you could update the list at that time.

Comment: That's a great idea! I would still have to update the list on a regular base, as those 20 possibilities may change over time but that is manageable. Thanks a lot!